# How to set the length of a line in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I have some fibs extensions on the chart and I want to make the length of the lines smaller.

For example, you can make a line going full length across the chart, but how do I change length?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

// First we make a trend line, and then extend

```
highLine = line.new(x1=bar_index[50], y1=high[50], 
 x2=bar_index[15], y2=high[15], width=3, color=color.green)
```

// ...

// Extend existing trend line

```
line.set_extend(id=highLine, extend=lineExtend)
```

more on: https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/extend-trend-line-input/

Comment: That's the line width. I want to know how to change the length of a line.